# Unmodifiable List Wrapper Which Exposes A Different Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a `List<ParentObject>` where `ParentObject` is defined as:

```
public class ParentObject
{
  ChildObject child1;
  // and other stuff...
}
```

I would like to expose that `List<ParentObject>` to others as an **unmodifiable** `List<ChildObject>` by constructing a wrapper list:

```
public class WrapperList implements List<ChildObject>
{
  List<ParentObject> delegateList;

  public WrapperList( List<ParentObject> delegateList )
  {
    this.delegateList = delegateList;
  }

  // fill in java.util.List methods...
}
```

I can take this approach and make it work, but this seems like a problem which may have been solved generally. Is there an existing library which provides a list wrapper like what I am proposing? Presumably I would define a translation method telling the wrapper list how to retrieve the `ChildObject` from a given `ParentObject`.

The basic question is: is this a good approach or is there a library (Guava or Apache Commons Collections or something) which already provides something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this with Guava would be

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(Lists.transform(parentList,
  new Function<ParentObject, ChildObject>() {...}));
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing List, extend AbstractList. If it's going to be unmodifiable, all you need to implement are `size()` and `get(int index)`, which are trivial.

`AbstractList` implements the rest by throwing `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`.

I don't know of any generic list that can provide what you ask but it wouldn't be the complicated to build (would just reflection).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can work this out using Guava and then Collections.unmodifiableList.
In guava, use [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html)